# Beginner issue: Why does this for loop return false?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am doing some assignements in JS, and I have written afunction to compare the ending of a string (str) and return true or false if it matches the "target" string (this could be done a lot easier, but this piece of mayhem is how I chose to go about it):

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let valid = true;
  
console.log(str.length);
  console.log(target.length);

  for(let i = 0; i < target.length; i++){
    if (str.substring(str.length - (i+1)) == target.substring(target.length - (i+1))){
      valid = true;
    }
    else{
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(valid);
  return valid;

}
```

So, this function actually works, but looking at it, I cant understand why...

If I run

```
confirmEnding("Testing123", "tin5123");
```

It should return true in my mind, but the for loop does not change the value of variable "valid" back to true after the 4th iteration of the for loop? (shouldnt the for loop iterate 5, 6 and 7 also and go back to "true" for "valid"?)

The answer I get from OpenAI is that the function is checking that the "target" matches the end of "str". How? I cant see anywhere that I have made any specific instruction to do that...

How does the function decide which value of the variable "valid" to return? Does it iterate through all and only return "if: valid = true" if ALL i are true? Why?

Thanks

Comment: Since `return valid` is at the end of the function, the last value of `valid` is returned (and chances are your loop is misbehaving). If `confirmEnding` is supposed to check whether the `str` simply ends with `target`, `confirmEnding("Testing123", "tin5123")` should _not_ return `true`.

Comment: Consider the oldest, most primitive debugging method: add a `console.log` inside that loop; print `i`, `valid`, `str.substring(str.length - (i+1))` and `target.substring(target.length - (i+1))` out and reason what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It works because it starts from the end

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let valid = true;

  for(let i = 0; i < target.length; i++){
    console.log(str.substring(str.length - (i+1)), target.substring(target.length - (i+1)))
    if (str.substring(str.length - (i+1)) == target.substring(target.length - (i+1))){
      valid = true;
    }
    else{
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  
  return valid;

} 

console.log(confirmEnding("Testing123", "tin5123"));
```

Why even bother with the loop?

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.endsWith(target)
} 

console.log(confirmEnding("Testing123", "tin5123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add some logging to the code** (this and/or using a debugger to step through the code, is the **most important** thing you can do when you trying to understand how code gets the result it gives):

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let valid = true;

  console.log(str.length);
  console.log(target.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    const a = str.substring(str.length - (i + 1));
    const b = target.substring(target.length - (i + 1))
    console.log(`comparing ${a} with ${b}`)
    if (a == b) {
      valid = true;
    } else {
      valid = false;
    }
  }

  console.log(valid);
  return valid;

}

confirmEnding("Testing123", "tin5123");
```

It compares the last character in each string, and then does nothing with the result.

Then it compares the last two characters in each string, and then does nothing with the result.

Then, several loops later, it compares the second string with the substring of the first string with finishes at the end and is the same length, and returns that result.

> It should return true in my mind, but the for loop does not change the value of variable "valid" back to true after the 4th iteration of the for loop? (shouldnt the for loop iterate 5, 6 and 7 also and go back to "true" for "valid"?)

No. You're comparing substrings from  to the end of the string. You're not comparing single characters.

> How does the function decide which value of the variable "valid" to return? Does it iterate through all and only return "if: valid = true" if ALL i are true? Why?

It returns the *last* value you give to `valid`, because that is the value it has when you `return` it.